# What is the solution for this decorator pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I've been asked some kind of interesting questions related to OOP.
Here's the question.

> Alice has started a restaurant and created software the determine the price of all the items on the menu
> She started by creating a class for each menu item so that the price can be calculated using an interface.

```js
interface HasPrice {
    getPrice(): number;
}

class Ramen implements HasPrice {
    getPrice() {
        return 5;
    }
}
class Spaghetti implements HasPrice {
    getPrice() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

> She then decided there should be topping so she used the decorator pattern.

```js
class RamenWithPork extends Ramen {
    getPrice() {
         super.getPrice() + 3;
    }
}
```

> This worked until she decided to expand the topping menu and it became too cumbersome to deal combinatorial amount of classes. How should she fix it?
>
> follow up question: With all the choices, customers have started asking whether or not their choice of ingredients contains certain allergens.
>
> Alice would prefer not to have to add a million methods to all her classes to specify true/false for each allergen. How can she add this check without having to add one function per allergen for each ingredient?

Comment: Are you expected to use just other patters for this exercise? I'm no expert but this feels the need of a Factory or AbstractFactory to create your ingredient classes

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance. This article gives you a good overview:
https://alligator.io/js/class-composition/

Comment: As you know, the main point of this question is to use interface for several ingredients. so we can get price by only with interface. is it possible to do with composition. i have no idea with composition yet.

Comment: I think with decorator pattern, there's no way to solve this. isn't it?

Comment: A starting point: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator